# How to display the imageview and textview using listview without baseadapter in android?

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

i want to display the imageview and textview using listview .But without using base adapter in listview.is this possible using ArrayAdapter?

```
final String[] menuitems = new String[] {   

            "Settings", 
            "Notifications",
            "Logout"
        };  

    int[] menuiicons = { R.drawable.logo, R.drawable.logo, R.drawable.logo  };



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

        mainListView = (ListView) findViewById( R.id.mainListView );
        ArrayList<String> menuitemList = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<Integer> menuiconsList = new ArrayList<Integer>();


        listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.listview_home, menuitemList);
        mainListView.setAdapter( listAdapter );
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not, because you need to populate the ListView through a a getView(..) method, and this is a BaseAdapter method. 
Is there a reason why you don't want to use BaseAdapter?

Answer (score 0):

of course you can use ArrayAdapter just override its getView method

Comment: can we use another layout in getview method

Comment: but i need to display without getview adapter method?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah  you can add text and images in arrayAdapter .

```
ArrayAdapter(context, resource, textViewResourceId, objects)
like this you can have lot few more methods .. her reource id your image.
```

and also have a look at this..

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html